# How to call Javascript function in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I'm getting an error as `myFunction()` IS NOT DEFINED:

```
app.controller('myctrl',function(){
    myFunction();
});

function myFunction() {
    debugger;
    document.getElementById("abc").disabled = false;
}
```

Here `myFunction` is `onclick="myFunction()"` but I'm trying to call it in my function
What mistake I'm doing? please help me

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message

Comment: @NicoHaase Here i m calling myFunction in onclick=myFunction()"   When i click on Button its Working But When i call in Function its calling but not working

Comment: Please add the **full and exact** error message to the question. I assume it is a problem of scoping

Comment: I also suggest you to provide a [mcve]. The piece of code you've shown doesn't seem to be errorneous by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be defining functions outside of your angular controller. When you do this, you lose the angular context since angular doesn't know it took place. You'll start seeing some wackyness such as two way data binding issues along with other things.

Secondly, you need to import the `$scope` module into your `controller` so you can define functions on it. There are other ways to do this, but this is the most common.

https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/ty43egxo/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click="alertAgain()">
   Show an alert
  </button>
</div>



const dontdothis = () => {
    alert('function should be within the angular controller');
};
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ($scope) => {
    dontdothis();

    $scope.alertAgain = () => {
        alert('this is an alert again');
    };
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

This is a [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) issue.

If you want to use a function from your html, you have to link your function to the scope of your controller, byt adding $scope. to myFunction, so you get

```
app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function() {
    $scope.myFunction();
}]);

function myFunction() {
    debugger;
    document.getElementById("abc").disabled = false;
}
```

Moreover, if your function job is to make an element noy disabled, you can u se ng-disabled,I made a [working example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kpyLb0ZVGySekEcO0r03?p=preview) using ng-disabled

Comment: You need to import `$scope` into your function. `$scope` is undefined in your answer. It's correct on your plunker though.

Comment: Indeed, edited my answer so now $scope is imported. Thanks !